# dropshadow() -i am going a project to shadow a clip polygon image

Tags: reactjs, next.js, import

drop shadow is giving me rectangle shape .instead of a clip shape

```
.main{
  position: relative;

  filter: drop-shadow(-10px -20px 0px rgba(150, 223, 150, 0.5));
}
.img{
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%);
  background-color: green;
}
```